# Am I consuming "roaming" services?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, roaming

I've borrowed an Android phone so I can decide whether to buy one. I have a GSM SIM without a data plan, but I am using Wifi that is broadcast from my other smartphone which does have a data plan.

**The phone's GSM signal icon has a tiny "R" that indicates that I am roaming -- why?**

My phone is an [HTC Desire Z](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_desire_z-3421.php) with (I think!) Android 2.3. 
Under `Settings > Mobile Networks` I have these settings:
Data enabled = unticked
International data roaming = unticked
National data roaming = unticked
Use only 2G networks = ticked

The notification list sometimes shows me a message that is too long to be displayed, but some googling tells me that this is the complete text:

> "You have lost data connectivity because you left your home network with data roaming turned off"

The notification list also shows that I am in fact on the correct network: My SIM card is from the provider "bob" and the phone shows that I am on the "bob" network.

**Am I consuming anything related to roaming? How can I ensure that I will *not* use roaming?**

Comment: In some ROM the display of 'R' will be bit confusing. The 'R' might be displayed in different colours to highlight roaming or not. To ensure, can you go to Settings -> About phone -> Status and see what the item "Roaming" shows? In my LG P500 when not in roaming it shows "Not Roaming". Probably this could clear if you are a victim of ambiguous display of 'R'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this [post from XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=4670769&postcount=5) will answer your question.

> This isn't an APN problem, it is a SIM problem.
>
> Your provider has one set of numbers on your card, and another set of
>   numbers that actually identify the network, and they don't match.
>   Technically, from the phone's point of view, you *are* roaming, even
>   if it is the same provider. From the provider's point of view, you
>   *aren't* roaming.
>
> Up until cupcake, we had that same problem here in Canada when using
>   the "Fido" network (which is owned and operated by "Rogers"). The
>   network identified itself as "Rogers", the SIM cards identify
>   themselves as "Fido", the phone think's its roaming.
>
> So; you don't need to worry about roaming charges when you are
>   actually connected to the correct network.
>
> BUT; You don't have an easy to read display to tell you when you are
>   *really* roaming, nor can you make configurations that are based on whether you are or are not roaming.

Comment: This could make sense, thank you! The "bob" network is a low-budget provider that operates on top of another provider ("A1"). So if my phone sees that it's on "A1" then this matches your explanation. It's just confusing because it still _shows_ "bob"...